# Java swing button doesn't add new container component

Tags: java, swing

I have the following swing App. The problem is that I want the on click button action to add new component to the Container c. Whenever the method `AddGraph()` is called separately inside the constructor the chart is added. However, if I call it inside `actionPerformed()` the chart isn't added.
I've tried making `AddGraph()` returning the chart object and then adding it in `actionPerformed()` but still not working. It should be something very basic but I cannot find the right way to do it.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

        ChartPanel chartPanel;

        public MainFrame(String title)
        {
            super(title);

    //      Set layout manager
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //      Create Swing components
            JButton button = new JButton("Click me");

    //      Add swing components to content pane
            final Container c = getContentPane();

            c.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            AddGraph(c);

    //      button behaviour here
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                    //AddGraph(c);

                }

            });
        }

        public void AddGraph(Container c)
        {

    .
    .
    .
            chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));



            c.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        }

    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding the component to the container? I don't see you doing that anywhere. Your `AddGraph` method should take the container as a parameter but I see you creating a new one which is not the same as the one in the `MainFrame` constructor.

Comment: I've changed this adding c as argument to AddGraph still the same result - working when called out of the button event and not working when called inside...

Comment: @user3259222 : Had you tried calling `frame.validate() and frame.repaint()` after adding `charPanel` inside the `actionPerformed` method? `JFrame` default layout is `BorderLayout` no need to set it explicitly. It would be wise if components are added to a `JPanel` instead and then setting this `JPanel` as the content pane for the `JFrame`, instead of adding components directly to the top level container, which will allow reusing the same code again, for another view.

Answer (score 0):

Make object of `container` i.e. `c` from constructor **public** and add the chartPanel in `c`

```
public void AddGraph(){
    .
    .
    .
    chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));

    //    Container c = getContentPane();

    c.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You AddGraph should be something like this:

```
public void AddGraph(Container c)
{
   .
   .
   chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
   chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));

   c.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

Then in the constructor you can call it like:

```
AddGraph(c);
```

Comment: I tried, still not working. The same outcome: calling AddGraph(c) inside the constructor works, calling it inside the button event does not work.

Comment: If what @nIcEcOw said doesn't work try creating a method that returns `ChartPanel` and then in the actionPerformed set content pane using `setContentPane(chartPanel)`. You can also choose to create the whole ChartPanel object inside the constructor.